# How can i remove string from variable after getting it?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public class PortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {
    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

        while(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {
            try {
                String receivedData = serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());
                tempData = tempData.concat(receivedData);
                System.out.println(tempData);
            }
            catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error in receiving response from port: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to remove Strings from variable `tempData`. If I put `tempData = "";` at the end of the `println`. I don't know why? Can someone help me to figure this out? If I don't remove the Strings from variable, my CPU usage is too high after a couple of minutes. I'm receiving String from GPS antenna, I'm getting the NMEA from it.

Comment: Why are you concatenating the strings? Do you really mean to print the whole thing again each time, as opposed to just the current / last event?

Comment: if im not concatenating the string, the output like this.
$
G
P
G
G
A and so on...

while if im concatenating it. the output like this .. $GPGGA and so on..

because i want to get time from NMEA code using GPS antenna. is there any other way sir?

Comment: P.S the first output i said is like every character prints and then new line again.

Comment: $GPGGA,011813.000,1437.9061,N,12100.2282,E,1,10,0.8,7.0,M,39.1,M,,0000*54
$GPRMC,011813.000,A,1437.9061,N,12100.2282,E,0.00,294.36,190916,,,A*6F

thats what i want to get output

Comment: Can you explain more about _remove Strings from variable tempData_?

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuffer or StringBuilder do such activity, doing this on String will be a costly operation in terms of memory.
Also it looks that you want to remove spaces from string use the trim() function for that before appending to StringBuffer

```
public class PortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

    StringBuffer sb = StringBuffer();

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        while (event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {
            try {
                String receivedData = serialPort.readString(event
                        .getEventValue());
                // check if string is not null before trim
                sb.append(receivedData == null ? "" : receivedData.trim());
                sb.append(",");
                //just print the receivedData in plac of whle sb again and again
                System.out.println(receivedData);
            } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error in receiving response from port: "
                        + ex);
            }
        }
        //check if the comma is the last index if so remove that
        String tmpData = sb.toString();
        tmpData = tmpData.replaceAll(", $", "");
        //print the entire data now
        System.out.println(tmpData);

    }
}
```